# oembed with multiple urls

Tags: api, embed, oembed

Is there a possibility to access oembed or a similar service like noembed with multiple urls like:

```
http://noembed.com/embed?url=[url1],[url2]
```

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO**.

[oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) spec does not allow such options

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can read the oEmbed specs as well =) But is there a similar service that allowes multiple urls?